# How to use iter_lines to show every line?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have the following code I wrote to play with requests. It only gives me one line rather than all. Is there a way to get all lines, and not just one? Thanks.

```
#import modules
import requests
import json
import re

#retrieve lichess games for a specific user
def get_lichess_games(username):

    api_session = requests.Session()
    api_headers = {
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer CZfakeeeeWo',
        'Accept'        : 'application/x-ndjson',
    }

    with api_session.get(f'https://lichess.org/api/games/user/{username}', headers=api_headers, stream=True) as response:
        for line in response.iter_lines():
            if not line:
                continue
            test = json.loads(line.decode('utf-8'))
            return test

data = get_lichess_games(username='putismydadsdad')
print(data['id'])
```

Example line:

```
{'id': 'dsVb', 'rated': True, 'variant': 'standard', 'speed': 'rapid', 'perf': 'rapid', 'createdAt': 1582685880089, 'lastMoveAt': 1582686389499, 'status': 'resign', 'players': {'white': {'user': {'name': 'gibaro', 'id': 'gibaro'}, 'rating': 1511, 'ratingDiff': 5}, 'black': {'user': {'name': 'putin', 'id': 'putin'}, 'rating': 1500, 'ratingDiff': -170, 'provisional': True}}, 'winner': 'white', 'moves': 'd4 d5 Nf3 Nf6 g3 Nc6 Bg2 e6 Nc3 Bb4 Bd2 Bxc3 Bxc3 O-O b3 b5 Qd3 a5 Qxb5 Ba6 Qxc6 Ng4 O-O Qc8 Qc5 Bxe2 Rfe1 Bxf3 Bxf3 Nxh2 Kxh2 Ra6 Qa3 f6 Qc1 e5 Bxd5+ Kh8 Bg2 exd4 Bxd4 c5 Bc3 a4 Qf4 g5 Qc4 Qf5 Qxa6 Qxf2 Qf1 Qxc2 Bxf6+ Rxf6 Qxf6+ Kg8', 'clock': {'initial': 600, 'increment': 0, 'totalTime': 600}}
```

So the problem is return. I can totally take return off and replace it with `print(['test'])` and get all of my lines.

But my end goal is to have a function that retrieves all values and passes them into the pipeline. Then I can just call my function in different places and ask for a different piece of data i nthose situations. So examples;

```
get_lichess_games(username='putin')
print ids this time

get_lichess_games(username='putin')
print winners this time

get_lichess_games(username='putin')
print moves this time
```

Comment: If I take off that return how can I pass it into the pipeline like I am doing? I want to be able to pass the function and select any value I want like id, moves, winner, etc. I don't want to have to write a function for each value.

Comment: I don't understand, I feel like everything you just asked has been answered aside from the data. If you look at my header dict, it's ndjson. Then I use the json module later on. I added an example. I can take return out of my loop and replace it with print(['id']) and sure it will work. But then I can't reuse the function. I want to be able to pass the function and say, okay give me the id this time. Pass the function somewhere else and say, ok give me the winner this time. I don't want to write a function for every value.

Comment: The data I gave is an example of 1 line. I didn't think you needed all 320k lines. I assumed one line was enough. They are all the same. My mistake. I feel like there's enough info to deduce what I expect. I am using inter_lines which indicates there is more than one line & I provided an example line. You can't copy and paste the code because I don't think it's wise to post my API key or the user names. If you look at the code, the token has the word 'fake' in it. What I am trying to do is - Have a function that puts all values in the pipeline, then pass the function and call any value I like.

Comment: I added more info into the original post. Basically, my end goal is, write a function that retrieves all values. Every one. Then yields it or whatever so those values are in the pipeline. So a function that pulls all of the values in my example line. Then I pass the function and since the data is in the pipeline, I can return any individual piece I like. If you look at the original code - that is what happened, I could call any piece I wanted outside the function, but obviously the return broke the loop.